# I need a specific include page to display on my index.php according to a date range

Tags: php

I am looking to have a specific cfm page be included on my home page (index.php) according to a specific date. 
i.e.: 01/01/2013 - 05/15/2013 display wet start.cfm  
      05/16/2013 - 05/31/2013 display first splash.cfm  
      06/01/2013 - 06/15/2013 display splashback.cfm
    and so on until the last event...  
      06/16/2013 - 12/31/2013 display season over.cfm

My include pages are listed below, but I can not figure out how to get the correct if-else statement.

```
<center><b>Our Next Event:</b></center>
```

`<?php include '../includes/events/wet start.cfm'; ?>`
`<?php include '../includes/events/first splash.cfm'; ?>`
`<?php include 'includes/events/splashback.cfm'; ?>`
`<?php include '../includes/events/mardi gras.cfm'; ?>` 
`<?php include '../includes/events/fiesta.cfm'; ?>`
`<?php include '../includes/events/steak feed.cfm'; ?>` 
`<?php include '../includes/events/luau.cfm'; ?>`
`<?php include '../includes/events/tiki.cfm'; ?>`
`<?php include '../includes/events/toga.cfm'; ?>`
`<?php include '../includes/events/lumberyard.cfm'; ?>`
`<?php include '../includes/events/royal court.cfm'; ?>`
`<?php include '../includes/events/bullards bar.cfm'; ?>`
`<?php include '../includes/events/dance party.cfm'; ?>`
`<?php include '../includes/events/houseboat.cfm'; ?>`
`<?php include '../includes/events/season over.cfm'; ?>`

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
<?php
// function that will return the file path for the current event as a string
function getCurrentEventFilepath() {
    // list all the events, with start date => file name
    // make sure they are sorted by date, or do sorting before you proceed
    $eventList = array(
        '2013-01-01' => 'start',
        '2013-05-16' => 'splash',
        '2013-06-01' => 'splashback',
        '2013-06-15' => 'mardi_gras',
        '2013-06-30' => 'fiesta'
    );
    // prepare some variables
    $tmpFile = '';
    $today = new DateTime("now");
    // loop through the event list
    foreach ($eventList as $dateString => $file) {
        // construct a date based on the dateString
        $date = new DateTime($dateString);
        // if the date is later then today
        if ($today < $date) {
            // return the path based on filename from the previos iteration
            return '../includes/events/'.$tmpFile.'.cfm';
        } else {
            // store the filaname in our temp variable
            $tmpFile = $file; 
        }
    }
    // if still here, it should be the last event in the list we want
    return '../includes/events/'.$tmpFile.'.cfm';
}

// fetch the current event file path, and do an include
include getCurrentEventFilepath(); 
?>
```

I put plenty of comments in the code, but feel free to ask if you want further explaination